# AWS Api Gateway proxy for s3 bucket with Serverless Framework

Tags: amazon-s3, proxy, aws-api-gateway, serverless-framework

I am deploying a project with the Serverless framework that includes different resources (a lambda function, cognito user pool, cognito identity pool, etc...)

For a previous project, we created from the console (so manually) the configuration for a second Api Gateway (in addition to the one that we configured with Serverless on the lambda) to just be the proxy for our s3 bucket, so we were able to add and get files from the bucket without using the lambda.

Now, I want to make the exact thing to this new project, but instead making the second Api Gateway manually from the console, there is a way to declare this proxy directly from Serverless configuration?

I searched for different solutions, but I didn't find any guide for this.

What I'm trying to make in the configuration is what this [amazon guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/en_pv/apigateway/latest/developerguide/integrating-api-with-aws-services-s3.html#api-items-in-folder-as-s3-objects-in-bucket) explains.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [this](https://github.com/horike37/serverless-apigateway-service-proxy#s3) plugin that allows setting up API Gateway service proxies very easily (I'm one of the collaborators).

`serverless.yml` example:

```
service: s3-proxy

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs10.x

plugins:
  - serverless-apigateway-service-proxy    

custom:
  apiGatewayServiceProxies:
    - s3:
        path: /s3/{key}
        method: post
        action: PutObject
        bucket:
          Ref: S3Bucket
        key:
          pathParam: key
        cors: true

resources:
  Resources:
    S3Bucket:
      Type: 'AWS::S3::Bucket'
```

Comment: can I use it in the main serverless.yml file of the project also if I'm using python 3.7 and not nodejs?

Comment: Yes you can use it in the main `serverless.yml`. You can use it with python. The plugin just adds resources to your CloudFormation template based on the amazon guide you provided, since there is a lot of boilerplate if you want to do it your self.

Comment: I saw in the github project that also supports SNS service... but seems only for topics... I can configure it in some way to send the platform_endpoint to the Gateway to send notification to a single device or it's not supported?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question about SNS. Do you mind describing your scenario in an issue in the GitHub repo?
The plugin allows you to setup an API gateway to directly publish a message to SNS using a URL. If you connect a subscriber to the SNS topic it will receive the published message.

Comment: I don't want to publish a message to a topic but publish to a single registered device (by it's ARN of when it registered to the SNS service)

Comment: What do you mean by a "registered device"? Do you mean you want to publish a message directly to a subscription without going through a topic?. As far as I know you can only publish to a topic. If you want to control which message goes to which subscriber you can use a filter policy.

Comment: no, the device is not subscribed to any topic... Amazon SNS let you create a Platform Application linking for example the Firebase console for an Android app to SNS, then the device can register to SNS Platform Application (NOT a topic) and SNS will generate an ARN of the specific device. That ARN can be used to publish a notification to that specific device. Just to explain better, when you subscribe to a topic you obtain a similar result, in fact the same ARN is generated and added to the list of ARNs subscribed to that topic, so a notification can be send to all of them.

Comment: In that case I think you might be able to do it with the plugin by using a custom request template as described here https://github.com/horike37/serverless-apigateway-service-proxy#sns-1 and replace `TopicArn` with `TargetArn`. I think it would be better to discuss this as an issue in the plugin repo.

Comment: for sure! I will create an issue if needed for further request... now I need to know one thing... I tried the plugin for the S3 proxy, and I saw that it automatically creates a Role to link to the GW... There is a way to link a specific Role created by me in the serverless file to those S3 proxies endpoint? and how can I declare the binary types to be enabled on the GW? since the files sent are not uploaded correctly because the binary type `image/png` for example is not configured in the GW